# End user to create custom field and categories

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, modal-dialog

I would like to get your input on the following scenario.
I have Items.php page that user can view their items. they can also add custom items.
What I am trying to accomplish is the following:

1. Once they create a category, a new table is create with the category as the table name and a new ID primary key in the table with the same name_id.
2. Add new fields to be associated with the category and define their type.
3. When this category is selected in a drop down, the category associated fields show up and they can add information.

So far, I was able to have the user create a new category which create a table and an ID column. I know I may be not explaining enough, but I will appreciate your input if you ever done something similar.

Comment: A new *table*? Are you sure? This sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: I wouldn't allow a user to have control of your database like that. You're much better off, and safer, to create a new record in a table called categories. To allow the 'new fields to be associated with the category' to be created you could create an association table which has columns including the category id, and the value for the information.

Comment: what I am trying to do is to have users create categories (Server, Network Device for example) each record has its own fields (server IP or Network speed field) so each category will need to be on its own table unless you know a different way of doing this.so the fields are not the same.